# Upgrade to Fedora 33 now password don’t work

Tags: linux, fedora

I upgraded to Fedora 33 and now my login password no longer works. How can can I fix it? I can bring up the window with control, alt F2, then what do I type to get rid of login password?

Comment: `then what do I type to get rid of login password?` – Does this mean you can actually log in using tty2?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to log into your own (user) account, or into the root account? If you can log in as root, you can turn off the password prompt on your regular user account by clearing out the 2nd (password) field in /etc/passwd, like this:

jpublic::5471:1650:John Q Public:/users/jpublic:/bin/bash

Notice the colons are next to each other.
Often times you'll be removing a single x.
Save and exit.
Run pwconv with no arguments, then try logging in.

If the root password is not available, you're in a worse situation. I had that happen recently when my vim started damaging the first 2 characters of files as soon as they opened. Recovery required creating a boot CD using a Knoppix ISO file I downloaded, then booting off it. Once in Knoppix, I located my original root filesystem and cd'd to the (now damaged) /etc/passwd file, fixed the damage, then rebooted the normal way and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you log in as root?  If so, simply `passwd *username*` should work, replacing *username* with the user account name whereof the login password doesn't work.

If your root password doesn't work either, you'll have to get a root shell through replacing the init process during boot.  Start by rebooting into GRUB.  Select the Fedora installation (usually the top entry), then press E to edit the entry options.

You'll see a lot of text, but the important line is the one that begins with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-...`.  Add `init=/bin/bash` to the end of the line, separated by a space.  Make sure there are no trailing spaces.

Now, press `Ctrl-X` to 'boot' with the new options.  Hopefully, you'll see a command line wherein you are logged in as root, and there is no hostname.
[image]
Therefrom you can simply mount the root filesystem `mount -o rw /` and set the passwords `passwd root` and `passwd *username*`.

Comment: Im sorry I’m new with this. When I bring up the command window it asks for user and then password just like when you let the whole thing load. I don’t think I can get to root either. When I try and edit the boot Linux lines it says it cant mount the file and ends up locked and won’t do anything